# redirect only base URL request to page, not child urls

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on a Wordpress site that uses an e-commerce engine for some of the account functions of logged in users.  I am able to control what pages users see and what content they are able to interact with in most places on the site, however one URL needs to be directed to the account page, but I do not need redirection on the not child pages.

Example:

**mydomain.com/baseurl** --> should redirect to customer account page.  But I do not want to redirect child pages.

**mydomain.com/baseurl/some-child-page/product** --> should ***not*** redirect anywhere and just display normally.

I already tried the htaccess:

```
Redirect /baseurl http://mydomain.com/customer-account-page
```

but this logically affects child pages as well.

Is this possible to redirect only the base URL page?  I don't want to disrupt the existing software that displays some dynamic content on the base URL page, so I just want to direct away from it automatically as I don't want the users to ever see that page.

I didn't see my exact question anywhere else here, so I hope someone can direct me.  Thanks!

Comment: Just the .htaccess rule I showed above.

Comment: @gebearnold: I do not see the rule within your question. Please, include it.

Comment: Here: "Redirect /baseurl http://mydomain.com/customer-account-page"

Comment: @gebearnold: I have updated your question so the code is properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root folder of your domain.

```
RewriteRule ^baseurl$ http://mydomain.com/customer-account-page [L,R]
```

If the URL you want to redirect is http://mydomain.com/some-folder/to-redirect.php then the rule would be

```
RewriteRule ^some-folder/to-redirect\.php$ http://mydomain.com/customer-account-page [L,R]
```

**EDIT**

Add the following to your .htaccess file in the root directory of `mydomain.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


#redirect mydomain.com/shop with or without trailing slash
RewriteRule ^shop/?$ http://mydomain.com/customer-account-page [L,R]
```

Comment: I tried a couple things, but can you give me an example of the baseurl noted above, or how to use that piece of this?  Thanks :)

Comment: @gabearnold I have one example above. If it does not make sense, then provide the URL you want to redirect and I will update the rule

Comment: mydomain.com/shop should redirect to mydomain.com/customer-account-page

But - mydomain.com/shop/some-product should not redirect anywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience in helping me understand this.  It works perfectly and I really really appreciate your help!

Comment: One other quick question on this, can you explain how it only redirects the one page? :)

Comment: @gabearnold The first part of the rule, the target, only matches the shop URL, no other. Without the `$`, which indicates the end, it would match any URL starting with shop.